# I keep getting an" EIO: i/o error: when I use the expo init command

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

Just recently looked into React-Native development with expo(noob here). Used the "expo init" command on the Linux command line and keep getting this:

```
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:564:3)
at tryReadSync (fs.js:349:20)
at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:378:19)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:22)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/onlyartist9/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.2/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/src/add/operator/multicast.ts:3:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
```

What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Was using the Linux command line which I guess did not support arrow options. After scouring through `expo init --help`

I was able to choose the template I wanted and subsequently running a command directly

Use `expo init -t [ProjectName] [TemplateType]`

TemplateType comes in three variants namely: "blank", "tabs", "bare-minimum".